# checker in 4 colors

Tags: scripting, shaders, osl

Could someone tell me how I can create a checker in 4 colors in all faces?

I have already made this:

```
shader checker(

    point Pos = P,
    float Scale = 1,
    color Color1 = color(1,0,0),
    color Color2 = color(0,1,0),
    color Color3 = color(0,0,1),
    color Color4 = color(0,1,1),

    output color Col = 0

  ){

    point p = Pos * Scale;
    int x = (int)mod(p[0],2.0); // [0.0, 2.0) or [0.0,1.9999...]
    int y = (int)mod(p[1],2.0); //(int) convert to 0 or 1
    int z = (int)mod(p[2],2.0);

    if(x%2==1 && y%2==1 && z%2==1){
        Col = Color1;
    }
    if(x%2==0 && y%2==0 && z%2==1){
        Col = Color2;
    }    
    if(x%2==1 && y%2==0 && z%2==1){
        Col = Color3;
    }    
    if(x%2==0 && y%2==1 && z%2==1){
        Col = Color4;
    }

    if(x%2==1 && y%2==1 && z%2==0){
        Col = Color2;
    }
    if(x%2==0 && y%2==0 && z%2==0){
        Col = Color3;
    }
    if(x%2==1 && y%2==0 && z%2==0){
        Col = Color4;
    }
    if(x%2==0 && y%2==1 && z%2==0){
        Col = Color1;
    }
  }
```

[image: Checker]

But I get just 3 colors in 5 faces.

(one face from image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple: you should swap color 1 and 3 in second section.

[image]

Because you have 3d-texture second row must be inverted first row. If you arrange in right order you will get in `Z=0`: 1, 3, 4, 2 and in `Z=1`: 2, 4, 3, 1

```
if(x%2==1 && y%2==1 && z%2==1){
    Col = Color1;
}
if(x%2==1 && y%2==0 && z%2==1){
    Col = Color3;
} 
if(x%2==0 && y%2==1 && z%2==1){
    Col = Color4;
}
if(x%2==0 && y%2==0 && z%2==1){
    Col = Color2;
}    


if(x%2==1 && y%2==1 && z%2==0){
    Col = Color2;
}
if(x%2==1 && y%2==0 && z%2==0){
    Col = Color4;
}
                                   // this two swapped: 
if(x%2==0 && y%2==1 && z%2==0){ 
    Col = Color3;
}
if(x%2==0 && y%2==0 && z%2==0){
    Col = Color1;
}
```